# Is it possible to save pre-compiled delegates that I pass to a method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, delegates, func

I have a method that takes a delegate and runs it on the DbContext.Local entity and if null, tries to find it in the database, as specified below.

```
   public static T FirstOrDefaultInLocalOrDb<T>(this DbSet<T> myTable, Func<T, string, bool> criteria, string input) where T : class
    {
        var output = myTable.Local.Where(o => criteria((T)o, input)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (output == null)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (u) => criteria(u, input);
            output = myTable.Where(predicate.Compile()).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

99% of the time it's finding it in the Local entity and does not need to go to DB.

In another part of my program, this line is calling this method 1000s of times, each time with a unique HomeId.

```
var currHouse = db.Houses.FirstOrDefaultInLocalOrDb2(delegate(House h, string value) { return h.AllHomesID == value; }, HomeId);
```

I've done some performance testing and I've realized that this method runs very slowly and I think it's because it has to compile the delegate every time it runs.

This method is used in other places too so I have to keep it generic like so, but I was wondering, as that line is essentially passing the same delegate to it each time, just with a different input value, is it possible to somehow pre-compile the delegate, so that the method doesn't need to compile the delegate every time?

UPDATE

I wrote this non-generic version of the method, which I think is what I'm trying to get my original method to do, just in a generic way. This method seemed to run much faster. Using System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch, the old method ran at about 100ms, whilst this one ran at about 7ms.

```
public static House FirstOrDefaultAllHomesIdInLocalOrDb(this DbSet<House> myHouseTable, string allHomesId)
{

    var output = myHouseTable.Local.Where(o => o.AllHomesID == allHomesId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (output == null)
    {
        output = myHouseTable.Where(o => o.AllHomesID == allHomesId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't slow because it's doing a table-scan and returning all the rows for your program to filter in-memory?

Comment: @Lasse - Well, I did try writing another method which just called the actual methods instead and it was much faster.

Comment: I can't vouch for why that other method is faster without seeing it.

Comment: @Lasse : fair enough, I'll paste it in

Comment: Obviously that code is going to run faster because EF is going to translate that into SQL, and not do the filtering in-memory.

Comment: @Lasse : But I thought the local entity in EF4 didn't access the DB? As I mentioned earlier, 99% of the time, that method will not access the database - it'll just find the in-memory version of the data and return it. The compiling to SQL bit takes even longer actually, but I'm not that concerned about it as it hardly ever needs to do it. But every single time it'll need to compile the delegate and run it against the Local entity.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem here is that you've declared your `criteria` as a `Func`, and not as an `Expression`.

This means that the query has to retrieve all the rows of `myTable.Local` into your application, and then run your delegate against them.

In other words, if you had changed the type to `Expression<...>` instead of `Func<...>`, the SQL executing would be executed *with* those criteria, *and* the "TOP 1" or whatever syntax your actual database engine requires.

Instead, you're basically executing `select * from myTable`, and then stopping on the first one.

Depending on how entity framework does it, it *might* yield the rows as it gets them from the database, but I doubt it, as not all database engines supports having multiple open cursors.

So in this case, if the table has 1 million rows, and 500.000 match, but you only want the first, you're still retrieving 500.000 rows and discarding the last 499.999 of those.